# variable no longer in scope within a socket message fuction?

Tags: node.js, sockets

This is a file that listens to messages on port 5000.
The console.log(status) within the function listen seems to be printing true and false 
However when exporting status to other files , I still get "none" instead of true and false ... Any suggestions?

```
var dgram = require('dgram');
var net = require('net');
var status="none";
var num=0;
var LOCAL_UDP_PORT=5000;


exports.listen=function(){
// TCP and UDP listeners
var sock = dgram.createSocket('udp4');
sock.on('message', function(msg, rinfo) {
    try{
            var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
            if (obj.class == ".Announce") {
                        if(obj.dev.id == "BLA") {
                           status=true;
                        }
                        else
                           status=false;

                         }
             console.log(status);
                }
    } catch(e){
        // do nothing an err
    }

});
sock.bind(LOCAL_UDP_PORT);

}

//Initialize
exports.status=status;
listen();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is,  status take a string object, and when you do `status=true/false`, the reference changes, but `exports.status` would hold the original reference

try

```
var status={val:"none"};
...

        status.val = true;
...

// in the module reading the value, 
var status = status.val;
```

Comment: I tried having var status=false at the start.I keeps giving me false even though the status inside the function is true

Comment: like I said, when you something like `status=true` or `status='none'`, even though you have said `exports.status=status` , `exports.status` would start referring to different objects...

Comment: I tried what you suggested .. I use in  status.val in the module that reads it .. Still none  .. sigh

Comment: @highriser like jfriend00 said, what time are you checking the `status` value?

Answer (score 0):

The incoming socket messages are asynchronous.  That means they arrive sometime in the future.  If you want to notify another module when they come in, then you will need to create a notification system and export the notification system so the other module can register an interest in getting notified.

You could create the notification system using an eventEmitter, using callbacks, using promises, etc...  Why technique you choose would determine exactly what you would export and how the caller would register their interest.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00 .. I am a newb .. so will look at how to create an eventEmitter :)